# Can we find $n$ points $A_{j}$ on the curve such that $\sum_{j=1}^n A_j=(2n,0)$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, trigonometry

Can we find $n$ points $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ on the curve $$\left(t+\frac{1}{t},\frac{(1-t^2)^2}{t^3}\right),\;-1<t<1,\;\;t\neq 0$$
such that $\sum_{j=1}^n A_j=(2n,0)$?

In the case $n=4$, computer found such 4 points, the sum of which is $(8.03,-0.05)$, the four points are
$(-6.94,-300.05),(4.99,100),(4.99,100),(4.99,100)$. Is that enough to show the existence in the case $n=4$ ?

An author claimed in his article that if $n=3$, then we cannot find such 3 points. But the details were omitted. If one can give proofs for the case $n=3$ that will be good.

Comment: What is the motivation for considering these conditions?

Comment: What were the counterexamples provided by the computer?

Comment: Put that information in the question. Answerers shouldn't have you read the comments to know your full details. @biiii

Comment: Ok. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I have revised the question~

Comment: @biiii For $n=3$, how about: Let $t_2 = t_3 \approx 0.12744256$ be the root of 
$4z^3-15z^2-6z+1 = 0$.
Let $t_1 \approx -0.1015571553$ be the root of
$2z^3 - 21z^2 - 12z - 1 = 0$.

Comment: It seems true. My friend also provided some examples (although the author said it is not true if $n=3$).

Comment: @cbi You may use @ otherwise I may not receive notification of your comment.

Comment: @RiverLi Oh I am new and don't know how to at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $n=4$ case, it looks like you want $t_2 = t_3 = t_4$.  The equations become
$$ \eqalign{t_1 + \frac{1}{t_1} + 3 t_2 + \frac{3}{t_2} &= 8\cr
\frac{(1-t_1^2)^2}{t_1^3} + \frac{(1-t_1^2)^2}{t_1^3} + \frac{3 (1-t_2^2)^2}{t_2^3} &= 0\cr} $$
Discarding the solution $t_1 = t_2 = 1$, I get (with Maple's help)
$$ t_2 = \frac{2 t_1^2}{3} - \frac{31 t_1}{3} - \frac{4}{3}$$
where $t_1^3 - 15 t_1^2 - 9 t_1 - 1 = 0$.  This has a solution in the desired interval, approximately $t_1 = -0.147955904479, t_2 = 0.2101383127306$.

Comment: Yeah this solution should be the one in the question.

Comment: Sorry I forget to accept.